# Facing issue while adding php Ad Code in Function.php Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I have a blog on WordPress, and now I want to monetize the blog. I signup with websites so that I can display their adds on my blog.
Now the main issue I am facing is, they gave me a javascript code which I need to paste on my website.
The code they gave me is :-

```
<div id="zergnet-widget-68695"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var zergnet = document.createElement('script');
        zergnet.type = 'text/javascript'; zergnet.async = true;
        zergnet.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + '//www.zergnet.com/zerg.js?id=68695';
        var znscr = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        znscr.parentNode.insertBefore(zergnet, znscr);
    })();
</script>
```

Now I want to paste code through function.php, different code for different locations.
I search on google for help but the code they suggested me, none of them are working.
I want to add 4 different code on 4 different locations

1. pre_get_comments
2. get_sidebar
3. get_footer
4. the_post

As per the reference websites, the code they gave me is mentioned below, but after putting this code in website it shows only PHP Error.

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', function () { ?>
  <div id="zergnet-widget-68695"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var zergnet = document.createElement('script');
        zergnet.type = 'text/javascript'; zergnet.async = true;
        zergnet.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + '//www.zergnet.com/zerg.js?id=68695';
        var znscr = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        znscr.parentNode.insertBefore(zergnet, znscr);
    })();
</script>
<?php } );
```

Can anyone help me out, which code I put in Function.php. I will be really thankful.